# I am trying to do a penetration test on my cellphone hotspot; but aircrack keeps throwing me an error

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu

I was trying to bruteforce into my cellphone hotspot just for testing purposes and I couldn't get it to work right.

This is what I have basically done.

```
airmon-ng start wlan1
```

`airodump-ng mon0`

```
airodump-ng --bssid number -c 1 --write WPAcrack mon0


aireplay-ng --deauth 100 -a F8:7B:7A:69:9F:0F mon0
```

And, I tried to change the channel according to this cite ; but couldn't do it. Here is what the command prompt has showed me about aircrack. Why, do I need to specify an essid? I am running ubuntu and I tried to run this command; but it said command not found. 
`root@ubuntu:~# yaourt -S compat-wireless-patched
yaourt: command not found`

http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/fix-channel-1-glitch-airodump-latest-kernel-0132161/

```
root@ubuntu:/media/A000B2F200B2CF12_# sudo aireplay-ng --deauth 100 -a 

 F8:7B:7A:69:9F:0F mon0
 19:33:02  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: F8:7B:7A:69:9F:0F) on       channel -1
19:33:02  mon0 is on channel -1, but the AP uses channel 1
Please specify an ESSID (-e).
```

NOTE: I have no service its just for penetration testing.

I also think it might be a kernel bug according to my research that makes the monitor mode to be stucked in -1 which is a glitch. I also tried to follow tutorials on youtube; but there to old. I'm trying to patch the bug via tutorial to allow me to penetration test my cellphone hotspot.

Comment: From what I'm reading, the command that failed is meant to download and build packages from source via the Arch Linux community repository (through GitHub or otherwise?)... I would recommend simply trying `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` and seeing if that might fix your issue.

Comment: It just seems confusing with all these tutorials that don't seem to work.

Comment: This seems to be one of those problems where it might be your wireless card or it might be a bug in the software. In which case you know what to do. I wouldn't recommend trying to fix it yourself unless you already know hot to modify its source code. So I would say try other versions of the software (update/upgrade or reinstall the version you have). If that doesn't work, all you could really do is try is on different copies of Linux with different wireless cards. Maybe try it on a VM and set a USB wifi device to passthrough (VMWare Player supports this).

Comment: Are there any alternatives like aircrack besides reaver

Comment: I'm going to try to use different alternatives to aircrack it has to be a bug and I'll try to report it so it can be fixed. It just doesn't look like it is going to work until the bug is patched.